# Django SuspiciousOperation returns as HTTP 500 on Google App Engine, not HTTP 400 as expected

Tags: python, json, django, google-app-engine

Using Python 2.7, Django on Google App Engine. I'm trying to do some simple URL checking, including checking a JSON data payload, and return a meaningful error to the user. What I have coded is basically this:

```
from django.core.exceptions import SuspiciousOperation
...
def check(self, request):
    json_data = json.loads(request.body)
    if not json_data:
        raise SuspiciousOperation('Required JSON data not found in the POST request.')
    ...
```

But, when I test this in debug mode (DEBUG = True in settings.py) by omitting the JSON data, instead of returning a HTTP 400 as I expect from SuspiciousOperation, I get an HTTP 500 that contains my error message "Required JSON data not found in the POST request." The same thing occurs if I check for a valiud URL with URLValidator(): I can correctly test for a good or bad URL with the URLValidator(), but if I try to raise a custom message on a bad URL with SuspiciousOperation I get HTTP 500 instead of 400.

How can I return a meaningful error to my caller without the server error obfuscating everything when Debug is turned back off and crashing the process in the process? Is SuspiciousOperation not supported by GAE?

Comment: This wouldn't have anything to do with GAE; SuspiciousOperation is caught by [`django.core.handlers.BaseHandler`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/handlers/base.py#L179) and the normal error-handling response is invoked. Have you configured any special error handlers in Django?

Comment: Just double-checked that, and no, it is exactly as you see it. No other special error handling or custom exceptions are defined.

Comment: FYI Django version is 1.5.11

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue raised about this on [Django's bug tracker](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19866) and it looks like it was fixed in 1.6 but not backported. Indeed, SuspiciousOperation is handled by a catch-all in 1.5.11 (django/django/core/handlers/base.py line 173):

```
except: # Handle everything else, including SuspiciousOperation, etc.
  # Get the exception info now, in case another exception is thrown later.                  
  signals.got_request_exception.send(sender=self.__class__, request=request)
  response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
```

Comment: Thanks. And, GAE only "supports" 1.5 at this time. I'm going to try to get the steps described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207326/getting-django-1-7-to-work-on-google-app-engine) to "upgrade GAE to support a later Django version".

Comment: OK, I worked around it by hacking the GAE SDK's Django 1.5 django/django/core/handlers/base.py and adding the exception block for SuspiciousOperation from the Django 1.7 copy. Of course, next time I upgrade GAE SDK blehhhhh. Some things in Django 1.7 and 1.9 seem to break core functionality in GAE and vice versa so I'm not going to add them to GAE at this time.

Comment: Got Django 1.9 up and running on GAE. That solved my problem.