# Google App Engine Flask Project with PyCharm - sys.path.insert, virtualenv, site-packages

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, virtualenv, pycharm

I have a Hello World project with the following code:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), 'venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages'))

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The first 3 lines are necessary, otherwise I get this error message in console

```
from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Those first 3 lines, especially the sys.path.insert, are a bit ugly - is there another way I can set up the system paths with site-packages without having to declare it this way in code?

I'm using a virtualenv in case that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [vendoring](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring) mechanism to set up third party libraries for App Engine app. No need to modify `sys.path` in your files. Create **lib** directory directly in your application root and tell your app how to find libraries in this directory by means of `appengine_config.py` file.

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

Use pip with the -t lib flag to install libraries in this directory.

```
$ pip install -t lib [lib-name]
```

Or

```
$ pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26212173/3029175) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `sys.path.insert`

> PyCharm --> Preferences --> Project Interpreter --> Click on Gear Icon -->
>   Add Local --> `<browse to your virtualenv>`/bin/python --> OK

Now when you run your project by right clicking your flaskapp.py --> Run make sure the virtualenv is attached to it, by clicking on the down arrow --> edit configuration --> check `Python interpreter` that the virtualenv you had specified before is actually used by PyCharm.

[image]
[image]

Comment: No luck. Best I've managed is to move those 3 lines to app engine_config.py.